# Using "getElementById" for only letting letters&numbers&underscores for input

Tags: javascript, html

I want to allow only letters, numbers and underscores as input. My current code (below) only returns the error for dash and space.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  
  //for space
  var n = x.includes(" ");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
  
  //for dash
  var d = x.includes("-");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;

  if (d == true && n == true) {
    document.getElementById("demobox").innerHTML = 'MISTAKE!!! CAMPAIGN NAME INCLUDES SPACE & DASH!!!';
    document.getElementById('demobox').style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000";
  } else if (n == true) {
    document.getElementById("demobox").innerHTML = 'MISTAKE!!! CAMPAIGN NAME INCLUDES SPACE!!!';
    document.getElementById('demobox').style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000";
  } else if (d == true) {
    document.getElementById("demobox").innerHTML = 'MISTAKE!!! CAMPAIGN NAME INCLUDES DASH!!!';
    document.getElementById('demobox').style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demobox").innerHTML = 'GOOD TO GO!';
    document.getElementById('demobox').style.backgroundColor = "#008000";
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Campaign Name Checker</h3>
<input id="myText" placeholder="Please enter Campaign Name Here to check if campaign name includes space(s) or dash(s)">
<div id="demobox"></div>
<p>Example: Ingles_Monroe_XXX89000_OXX_V2_Video</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Check it!</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Hello Curious_MInd, I coulnt change these code into as "accept only /^[A-Za-z]+$/". Current code only returns error for dash and space. But I want to return error for all characters except etters&numbers&underscores.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reason you're repeatedly calling `document.getElementById` on the exact same element? Why not call it once then keep a reference to the result? Similarly, there's much redundant code (3 instances of making the background red - all 3 for a unmet constraint, why not just apply it once in the case constraints aren't met?)

Comment: Hi  Enhzflep, at first I just wanted to return specific error messages for each character for making things more clear to find which character is missing. But now I just wanna return only 1 error message with all not allowed chars. So thats why I wanna use "accept only /^[A-Za-z]+$/" format but I couldnt did it. I am little newbie to coding in html/javascript

Comment: @Leon - Sure, I'd wondered if that may have been the case. Have you considered a function that performs 1 task and one task only? I'm thinking of a function that takes the string to be checked as the input and returns a value that signifies whether the input was okay or whether it was wrong (and why). You could then grab the name, run it through the function, then decide on how you'd like to update the screen.

Comment: @Leon I've added an answer for you. Have a look on it, Hope this will help you out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<h3 style="font-family: Onyx; color: white; font-size: 33px; text-align: center;">Campaign Name Checker</h3>

<div style="text-align: center;"><input size="111" name="Giris" id="myText" value="Please enter Campaign Name Here to check if campaign name includes space(s) or dash(s)">
</div>

<div style="text-align: center;" id="demobox"></div>
<p style="color: white; text-align: center;">Example: Ingles_Monroe_XXX89000_OXX_V2_Video</p>
<div style="text-align: center;"><big style="font-family: monospace;"><button onclick="myFunction()">Check it!</button></big></div>




<p style="color: rgb(0, 64, 98);" id="demo"></p>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    // if includes somthing other then _ letters digits
    if (x.search(/[^_a-z\d]/i) !== -1) {
      document.getElementById("demobox").innerHTML = 'MISTAKE!!! CAMPAIGN NAME HAS INCORRECT FORMAT!!!';
      document.getElementById('demobox').style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("demobox").innerHTML = 'GOOD TO GO!';
      document.getElementById('demobox').style.backgroundColor = "#008000";
    }






  }
</script>
```

You may use `/[^_a-z\d]/i` regexp for catch NOT (underscores, letters, numbers)

If you want to display in your error which symbol is incorrect - use `match` instead:

```html
<h3 style="font-family: Onyx; color: white; font-size: 33px; text-align: center;">Campaign Name Checker</h3>

<div style="text-align: center;"><input size="111" name="Giris" id="myText" value="Please enter Campaign Name Here to check if campaign name includes space(s) or dash(s)">
</div>

<div style="text-align: center;" id="demobox"></div>
<p style="color: white; text-align: center;">Example: Ingles_Monroe_XXX89000_OXX_V2_Video</p>
<div style="text-align: center;"><big style="font-family: monospace;"><button onclick="myFunction()">Check it!</button></big></div>




<p style="color: rgb(0, 64, 98);" id="demo"></p>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    // if includes somthing other then _ letters digits
    var result = x.match(/[^_a-z\d]/i)
    if (result) {
      document.getElementById("demobox").innerHTML = 'MISTAKE!!! CAMPAIGN NAME HAS "' + result[0] + '"!!!';
      document.getElementById('demobox').style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("demobox").innerHTML = 'GOOD TO GO!';
      document.getElementById('demobox').style.backgroundColor = "#008000";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Smollet777 Thank you so so so much! It worked. Unfortunately since I am the new for the stackoverflow I could not give upvotes but thanks a lot my friend, you saved my hours.

Comment: @Leon do not worry. You just had to accept the answer. :)
I expand my answer. Take a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot Smollet777, this version is much much better for making the error clear, I mean for specifying it. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also use HTML5 form field validation, some JavaScript to customize the error message, and CSS pseudo classes for valid and invalid states.

**Note** that the regular expression is in the `pattern` attribute of the `input` element.

```js
// Add submit listener to the form element
document.getElementById("myForm")
  .addEventListener('submit',
    function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('valid name');
    }
  );

// Attach some custom HTML5 validation messages to myText
var myText = document.getElementById('myText');

myText.oninvalid = function(e) {
    e.target.setCustomValidity('');
    if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
        e.target.setCustomValidity('Use only letters, numbers, and underscores');
    }
};

myText.oninput = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.setCustomValidity('');
};
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 350px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
input::placeholder { color: white; }
input:invalid { background-color: #AA000080; }
input:valid { background-color: #00AA0080; }
```

```html
<h3>Campaign Name Checker</h3>
<form id="myForm">
  <input
    required
    id="myText"
    placeholder="Use only letters, numbers, and underscores"
    pattern="[\d\w_]+"
  >
  <div id="demobox"></div>
  <p>Example: Ingles_Monroe_XXX89000_OXX_V2_Video</p>
  <button type="submit">Check it!</button>
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this way after removing redundant codes e.g caching variables like `var demo = document.getElementById("demo");` . I guess this simple logic will help you understand what you've messed up. **By the way I can also do it by using regular expression way** e.g `/[a-z0-9_]/i` that will accept only letters, digits and underscores but that'll not clear your current understand of messing up.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  var demobox = document.getElementById("demobox");
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
  demo.innerHTML = x;
  
  //for space
  var n = x.includes(" ");
  demo.innerHTML = n;
  
  //for dash
  var d = x.includes("-");
  demo.innerHTML = d;


  if (d == true && n == true) {
    demobox.innerHTML = 'MISTAKE!!! CAMPAIGN NAME INCLUDES SPACE & DASH!!!';
    demobox.style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000";
    
  } else if (n == true) {
    demobox.innerHTML = 'MISTAKE!!! CAMPAIGN NAME INCLUDES SPACE!!!';
    demobox.style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000";

  } else if (d == true) {
    demobox.innerHTML = 'MISTAKE!!! CAMPAIGN NAME INCLUDES DASH!!!';
    demobox.style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000";
    
  } else {
    demobox.innerHTML = 'GOOD TO GO!';
    demobox.style.backgroundColor = "#008000";
  }

}
```

```html
<h3 style="font-family: Onyx; color: black; font-size: 33px; text-align: center;">Campaign Name Checker</h3>

<div style="text-align: center;" id="demobox"> </div>
<p style="color: black; text-align: center;">Example: Ingles_Monroe_XXX89000_OXX_V2_Video</p>
<div style="text-align: center;"><big style="font-family: monospace;">
Campaign Name: <input type="text" id="myText"/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Check it!</button></big></div>
<p style="color: rgb(0, 64, 98);" id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Curious_MInd for all your help :)